# jsTree delete icon for individual node with the delete action

Tags: jquery, plugins, jstree, jstree-dnd

I am using **[jsTree plugin](https://www.jstree.com/)** to display data in a *tree view* structure. However, I want to have a *delete icon/button on individual node* and on click of it, the node should get deleted (if it is a parent node then its child nodes also should get deleted)

Currently what I have now is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jsTree test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
    <button onclick="demo_create();" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> Create</button>
    <button onclick="demo_rename();" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Rename</button>
    <button onclick="demo_delete();" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</button>
</div>
<div style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="demo_q" style="box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px #eee; width:120px; margin:0; padding:6px 12px; border-radius:4px; border:1px solid silver; font-size:1.1em;" value="">
</div>
</div>
<div id="jstree" style="width:100%">
<ul>
  <li id="1">Root node 1
    <ul>
      <li id="2" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;width:500px" >Child node 1</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:right;" >Duration</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:right; width:150px;" ><button onclick="demo_delete();" type="button">&#215</button></div>
      </li>     
      <li id="3">Child node 2</li>
      <li id="4">Child node 3
      <ul>
          <li id="5">Child Node 3.1</li>
          <li id="6">Child Node 3.2</li>
          <li id="7">Child Node 3.3</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="8">Root node 2</li>
   <li id="9">Root node 3
   <ul class="jstreeul">
        <li id="10" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">
            <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;width:500px" >Child node 1</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:right;" >Duration</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>


function demo_create() {
var ref = $('#jstree').jstree(true),
    sel = ref.get_selected();
if(!sel.length) { return false; }
sel = sel[0];
sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});
if(sel) {
    ref.edit(sel);
}
};

function demo_rename() {
var ref = $('#jstree').jstree(true),
    sel = ref.get_selected();
if(!sel.length) { return false; }
sel = sel[0];
ref.edit(sel);
};

function demo_delete() {
var ref = $('#jstree').jstree(true),
    sel = ref.get_selected();
if(!sel.length) { return false; }
ref.delete_node(sel);
};

$(function () {  
var to = false;
$('#jstree').keyup(function () {
if(to) { clearTimeout(to); }
to = setTimeout(function () {
  var v = $('#jstree').val();
  $('#jstree').jstree(true).search(v);
}, 250);
});
});


$(function () {
$("#jstree").jstree({
"core" : {
  "check_callback" : function (op, node, par, pos, more) {
        if(more && more.dnd) {                
           return true;
        }
    }
 },  
"plugins" : [ "contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "state", "types", "wholerow", "contextmenubtn" ]
 });
 $('#jstree').on("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var v = $('#jstree').jstree(true).get_json();
    var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "http://localhost/test.php",
          data: {treedata: mytext},
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(resultData) {alert(resultData);alert("Save Complete") }
    });
    alert(mytext);
    return true;
 });  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Note:*** This does not include what I want.

Basically, I want to delete the node in a single click. Since my tree would contain more than 1000 nodes, it wont be a good idea to select the 500th node and then scroll up / down to click on the delete button. Instead I would want every individual node to have a delete / add button to either directly delete or create a child node on click of it.

Does anyone has a work-around for this ?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this. But haven't found one.

Comment: 2019, still no solution. I am stuck too.